# Detect if real client or a bot scanning for a image

Tags: php, image, http

I have been developing a screen shot website. I am having an issue with things like Skype, Slack, and direct images from automatically being detected.

Example:

The following screenshot is what gets copied to the clipboard:
http://rizzit.net/U1XNEZu.jpg

However, if whatever is trying to view the image is *not* a real client, direct them to: http://rizzit.net/direct/U1XNEZu.jpg

I can't think of a way on how I should get this done. If anyone could give me some pointers (not asking for spoonfeeding), that would be great.

Comment: Most (non-malicious) bots set a custom user agent, which you can check.

Comment: Although not that reliable, you can check the user agent and the remote address. Some bots will indicate that they are bots. Some will respect robots.txt. For others, I think I have seen someone made a list somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure the user agent one would work because I also want this to work on forums with [img] tags. Thanks though